# how to display checkboxlist items as linkbutton in asp

Tags: asp-classic, checkboxlist, linkbutton

how to display checkboxlist items as linkbutton in asp. I want it so that i can check selected items and click on correponding link button to get related information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a repeater to achieve this. In the itemtemplate of the repeater, use a checkbox and Linkbutton